# How to connect Qt program with other C++ program at runtime in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: qt, embedded, raspberry-pi4

A motor driver that is written in C ++ but cannot be connected to the Qt. We also talked to the manufacturer, but to no avail. But the Library works in Raspberry Pi and has example. Is there a way for the Qt program to connect and exchange data with the program running the engine library at the same time?

Comment: Without any details (what motor, what driver, what data do you want to exchange, ...), it is unlikely that someone will be able to help you...

Comment: What OS are you running on your pi4 ?

Comment: Question is a bit too vague but why not explore any of the multiple IPC mechanisms that linux provides? Or simply connect to a TCP port from the QT program and send commands to your motor driver program which should be listening on that port? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: As you want to connect to another C++ program, I assume the library and example are written in C++. What keeps you from integraing the example code in your own C++ program? (Assuming it is your Qt program) Also please keep in mind that C and C++ are very different languages and if you are only dealing with C++, the C tag should not be added.

Comment: Motor driver is for EPOS and OS is Raspbian. EPOS driver works in OS, but do not linked to Qt project.